# Syntax highlighting on GitHub Wiki refuses to work

Tags: github, pygments, gollum-wiki

This is driving me nuts.

Syntax highlighting doesn't work on a single Wiki page in a project on GitHub.

Take this page, for example: https://github.com/oscar-broman/PAWN-Boilerplate/wiki/Built-in-modules

Here's the source for it: https://gist.github.com/3128950

Oh, great, syntax highlighting works even there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the reason was I put `C++` in some places, only `c++` is accepted by the Wiki. If one place has the capital C, no highlighting will be done.